# Twitter login clarification

Tags: android, authentication, twitter

I want to create a twitter application in Android. For this I want to create a login page and login to twitter. For this should we need a Consumer key & Consumer secret Key. What does this mean. To create this login page should we need any this else other than a twitter account.
Please provide any code or link to help me.

Comment: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/implementing-sign-twitter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) First u must have a twitter account.

2) Then you must give access to your application to do that go to  [this](https://dev.twitter.com/) and sign in and create your application.

3)If u did it well, you will receive some information about your app including Access token,Access token secret,do not give this to any one(Access token,Access token secret) and make sure to keep your Access level to read and write.

4) Now you have done the basic part.now you want to do is the implementation the OAuth part.

5) To do that just follow [this](http://automateddeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/06/android-twitter-oauth-authentication.html)

5) That works for me hope you also can do that.

Comment: Twitter REST based API(via a JASON file) can be used is for your next part of the app.best way is to use Twitter4j try it, its amazing ...