# register mobile application to twitter

Tags: android, twitter, integration

I am developing android mobile application. I have to integrate **twitter** to my application.
I am facing a problem in very basic step that is **registration of application to twitter**.

My question is what the `URL` I have to provide in the registration form as my application is in developing phase and haven't any `URL` ? Also guide me about callback field.

Anybody can help me, as I need this for the proceeding...

Comment: Did you try with any possible URL? Do you have an error that's coming up? btw, I had blogged about twitter integration here http://blog.sheikhaman.com/2011/01/android-sign-in-with-twitter.html

Comment: No, I haven't... any web address can be given? e.g. http://abc.com

Comment: Check [this][1] same question it will solve your problem.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9817100/twitter-login-clarification/9817392#9817392

Answer (score 1):

Use any web url as your app url and use this url as a callback url.

```
CALLBACK_URL = "x-oauthflow-twitter://callback";
```

it may help you and if you have any query regarding that then tell me.

Comment: As you said that "Use any web url as your app url "... mean I can suggest it by myself that what the url of my application should... e.g. I want to set my application url as http://myfirstapplication.com.... is it correct?

Comment: you can use any url means google.com also, try this and tell me what happened.

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate Twitter using SocialAuth Android Library. See this post

[Android Twitter Connectivity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967625/android-twitter-connectivity)