# Twitter with Android Issue

Tags: android, twitter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [twitter integration on android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782743/twitter-integration-on-android-app)
>   [Android Intent for Twitter application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077008/android-intent-for-twitter-application)

Here I develop one Android application, I want to post message on twitter from my Android application.

I registered my app on Twitter, but what do I do next? I am totally confused.

Comment: check my answer on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9817100/twitter-login-clarification/9817392#9817392

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use library twitter4j to post message or you can integrate your app with twitter app or you can open this url in browser through your app to post message..

http://twitter.com/?status=message

for twitter4j find code here

https://github.com/itog/Twitter4j-android-Sample

last one is easy to use.